# c++ string += how is it implemented?

Tags: c++, string

I am just curious about the implementation of c++ string +=.

Is there any performance penalty for this?
Which one is supposed to be faster?

```
String a = "xxx";
a += "(" + "abcd" + ")"
```

or

```
String a = "xxx";
a.append("(");
a.append("abcd");
a.append(")");
```

Comment: Have a look at this:
[Efficient string concatenation in C++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611263/efficient-string-concatenation-in-c

It explains it very well.:)

Comment: @SpyrosR: It does explain it well, but for a different operator.

Comment: THanks! Actually my question is not well described... I changed it now and found the answer from what @SpyrosR posted.

Answer (score 2):

Given that they have word-for-word identical specs in the standard, it's hard to envisage a reasonable implementation where their runtime cost would differ:

> `21.4.6 basic_string modiﬁers [string.modiﬁers]`
>
> `21.4.6.1 basic_string::operator+= [string::op+=]`
>
> `basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& str);`
>
> 1 Eﬀects: **Calls `append(str.data, str.size()).`**
>
> 2 Returns: `*this`
>
> `...`
>
> `21.4.6.2 basic_string::append [string::append]`
>
> `basic_string& append(const basic_string& str);`
>
> 1 Eﬀects: **Calls `append(str.data(), str.size()).`**
>
> 2 Returns: `*this.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very surprised if the `+=` operator wasn't implemented by a call to `append`.

In fact, [SGI's documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) for `basic_string` indicates that:

> `basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& s)`  Equivalent to `append(s)`.

Furthermore, [the code](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string) reads:

```
basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& __s) { return append(__s); }
```

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string

Comment: The C++ stdlib is no direct copy of SGI's interface. Better use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D as reference, which tells basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference between them, In fact += operator's implemention just invoke append.
I read it from the STL code.

Comment: Just for reference, [STL is not the C++ Standard Library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/57318).