# Why are certain types of string concatenation significantly faster than others?

Tags: c++, string

Consider the following four cases:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s("Hi I'm Da");

 1. s += "n";
 2. s += 'n';
 3. s = s + "n";
 4. s = s + 'n';

    return 0;
}
```

Running this [test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892281/most-optimized-way-of-concatenation-in-strings) with the invocation:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -DVER=case -Wall -pedantic -pthread test.cpp -o test
```

using g++ version 4.8.3 20140624, I get the following results:

```
2.16172ms
0.48296ms
510.202ms
510.455ms
```

Now I can understand that `+=` is faster because you don't make a copy with `+` before assignment, but why does cases 1 and 2 show a significant difference compared to cases 3 and 4? Also, how does using double quotes or single quotes affect the concatenation speed?

Comment: With the string literal, the code needs to search for the null terminator. With the character literal, there's only one thing to do with no branching. The assignments produce a temporary object on the right.

Comment: They could really use an overload for string literals to capture their length at compile-time... That would speed things up some.

Comment: @Hi I'm Dan: You are referring to single quotes and double quotes as if they are some sort of cosmetic feature. In reality they mean completely different things. `"n"` is a C-style string, while `'n'` is not a string at all, but rather a single character. No wonder they are processed by completely different branches of code optimized for handling different general cases.

Comment: Do gcc strings still do copy-on-write?  Or do they now comply with the C++11 standard?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Look here for [C++11 `basic_string`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011): Status partial, non-conforming COW implementation. (The newest GCC, v 4.9.1)

Comment: That's quite a staggering performance difference -.-

Comment: Is the third option really this slow? Half a second? Or do you, like most sensible benchmarker, repeat it for thousands of times?

Comment: @KerrekSB "*With the string literal, the code needs to search for the null terminator*" and thats exactly why I don't unserstand why `std::basic_string` doesn't have a proper constructor for raw string literals (`template<std::size_t N> basic_string( const char (&str[N]) )`). The size of string literals is known at compile-time, and we still treat them as stupid null-terminated C-strings.

Answer (score 5):

```
s += "n";
```

This operates on the string in-place. There is possibility that memory reallocation will not be required. But string literals are zero-terminated character sequences, so the code needs to find the 0 value in memory after 'n'.

```
s += 'n';
```

This is similar to the first one, but it uses character literal instead of string literal. No need for searching for 0, so it may be faster.

```
s = s + "n";
```

Search for 0 is there, but what is more - much more - new temporary string object must be constructed, and most likely it means memory allocation, which is order of magnitude or more costly.

```
s = s + 'n';
```

May be faster than the previous one, but the difference caused by searching for 0 most probably is negligible compared with temporary object creation and allocation on the heap.

Note all "probably" and "may be". What I described may happen in popular compilers, but various optimisations may change the picture entirely.

Comment: That last paragraph is really crucial, because all of them have the exact same observable behavior, and thus can be optimized to the exact same instructions. (Just wanted to add some emphasis.)