# Why is the performance varies different when concatenating many strings?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I'm curious about the performance of concatenation of many strings. After reading [Efficient string concatenation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611263/efficient-string-concatenation-in-c), I made some test. But the result is different with different compilers.

Here is my code. (The timer in the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995693/5340808).)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure {
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F&& func, Args&&... args) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

std::string strAppend(const std::string &s, int cnt) {
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        str.append(s);
    return str;
}

std::string strOp(const std::string &s, int cnt) {
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        str += s;
    return str;
}

std::string strStream(const std::string &s, int cnt) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        oss << s;
    return oss.str();
}

std::string strReserveAndOp(const std::string &s, int cnt) {
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(s.size() * cnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        str += s;
    return str;
}

std::string strReserveAndAppend(const std::string &s, int cnt) {
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(s.size() * cnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        str.append(s);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    const std::string s("Hello world!");
    const int cnt = 1000000 * 5;
    std::cout << "ostringstream: " << measure<>::execution(strStream, s, cnt) << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "+= operator: " << measure<>::execution(strOp, s, cnt) << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.Append(): " << measure<>::execution(strAppend, s, cnt) << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.Reserve() & +=: " << measure<>::execution(strReserveAndOp, s, cnt) << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.Reserve() & s.Append(): " << measure<>::execution(strReserveAndAppend, s, cnt) << "ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Tested on [<kbd>**Ideone**</kbd>](http://ideone.com/QHr5lr) with GCC 5.1 gives the result:

```
ostringstream: 602ms
+= operator: 345ms
s.Append(): 336ms
s.Reserve() & +=: 224ms
s.Reserve() & s.Append(): 225ms
```

In which the `ostringstream` is the slowest and the `reserve()` speed up a little bit.

However when running the same code on Visual Studio 2015 community, the result is as follows:

```
ostringstream: 4413ms
+= operator: 9319ms
s.Append(): 8937ms
s.Reserve() & +=: 8966ms
s.Reserve() & s.Append(): 8815ms
```

Just pay attention to the relative speed, the `ostringstream` becomes the fastest and the `reserve()` seems not speed up.

So why is that happened? Compiler optimization or something else?

Comment: How did you compile with VS? `/O2` release?

Comment: @JameyD Thanks for point that out. I used `/Od` XD

Comment: libc++ is also an interesting case, it seems to be slower with the ostringstream but faster with append (and the same with reserve+append).

Comment: -1 for yet another speed question featurimg debug build timings.  Every profiling/speed question has that asked...  yet we still get debug build timing questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Jamey D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870760/jamey-d). Looks like what I'm guessing is right. After changing the optimization from `/Od` to `/O2`. The result is:

```
ostringstream: 1098ms
+= operator: 362ms
s.Append(): 356ms
s.Reserve() & +=: 216ms
s.Reserve() & s.Append(): 227ms
```

Which is the same with GCC 5.1.

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question.