# How to declare a string from multiple string variables C++

Tags: c++, variables

I want to know how I can declare a string from multiple string variables.

Example code:

```
std::string one = "one1";
std::string two = "two2";
std::string three = "three3";

std::string OneTwoThree = (one, " ", two, " ", three); // Here I want to save it as "one1 two2 three3"
std::cout << OneTwoThree;
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: just replace the commas with `+`.

Comment: And related : [Efficient string concatenation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/611263/327083)

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you @Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding all three strings as

```
std::string OneTwoThree = one+" "+two+" "+three;
```